# Counter does not set back to zero C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, counter

I have created one singleton class and when I exceute it for the first time just after starting the Visual Studio, it prints the expected result as the value of count is initially zero and it gets out of the loop when it reaches to one however, when I execute it for the second time, the counter value still remains as one and it does not set back to zero even after I stop debugging. Please help me out to find the solution for the problem. Thanks.
The code of my class is given below:

```
public partial class Singleton_class : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CEO c1 = CEO.GetCeoObject("Rahul", "MS", 28);
        CEO c2 = CEO.GetCeoObject("Ram", "MS", 26);
        Response.Write(c1.name + " " + c1.qualifiaction + " " + c1.age + "<br/>");
        Response.Write(c2.name + " " + c2.qualifiaction + " " + c2.age + "<br/>");
     }
}
namespace Singleton
{
    public class CEO
    {
        public static CEO c1;
        public static int count;
        public string name;
        public string qualifiaction;
        public int age;

        private CEO(string n, string q, int a)
        {
            this.name = n;
            this.qualifiaction = q;
            this.age = a;
        }
        public static CEO GetCeoObject(string name, string quali, int age)
        {
            if (count == 0) //this remains at one
            {
                c1 = new CEO(name, quali, age);
                count++;
            }
            return c1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Static variables are shared across all requests and live the life of the app domain. Static variables are lost if the system restarts your asp.net application.

Comment: not threadsafe, not the way should do singletons. http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx

Comment: your code looks really odd if you are incrementing `count++` then why are you checking if it `==0` it will work probably only 1 time based on a quick glance

Comment: @DJKRAZE Thanks for the reply. I'm doing so because I want to print only the values present for the first object, no matter how many objects user creates.

Comment: You have made a class that return statically the same object everytime the method GetCeoObject is called. Apart from the implementation weakness, this is a Singleton class. Now if you want to get distinct objects every time the method is called then return a new object and remove the count logic+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetCeoObject` creates the internal static object `c1` just the first time it is called.
When you call it a second time, the GetCeoObject return the `c1` created in the first call.
You assign it to a different variable, but this is the same reference to the `c1` instance assigned at the first variable. It is a reference to the same memory area.
When you print the values it is no surprise that it prints the same values.

Answer (score 5):

IIS doesn't restart the AppPool every time you attach the debugger, if you want to reset the counter you will have to rebuild you solution or touch you web.config file to force IIS to restart the AppPool (your static variables are kept until the AppPool recycles).

the Singleton pattern is a way to ensure you only have a single instance of a object in your entire application, so its important to have a private constructor on the class and make sure that the call to instantiate the instance is thread safe.

Below are two examples of how to implement a singleton in C#:

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton SingleInstance;

    static Singleton()
    {
        /* initializes the static field the first time anything is accessed on 
           the Singleton class .NET ensures threadsafety on static initializers. */
        SingleInstance = new Singleton(Datetime.Now);
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return SingleInstance;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Keep the constructure private on Singleton objects to avoid other instances being contructed
    /// </summary>
    private Singleton(DateTime value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public DateTime Value { get; private set; }
}
```

if you are using .NET 4 or above you can also use Lazy to simplify the singleton even more

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> LazyInstance = new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton(DateTime.Now));

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return LazyInstance.Value;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Keep the constructure private on Singleton objects to avoid other instances being contructed
    /// </summary>
    private Singleton(DateTime value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public DateTime Value { get; private set; }
}
```